# (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) on certain https domain on iOS9

Tags: nsurlconnection, ios9

I got this (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) error on certain domains iOS 9 with ATS enabled. I check the domain certificate, but couldn't figure our the cause of this issue.

For instance, https call to https://ad.doubleclick.net succeeded, but https call to https://gcdn.2mdn.net failed with -9802 error. I check the security details using firefox, they are both encryped as TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 128 bit keys, TLS 1.2, which meets ATS spec.

Why my code works with one but not the other? Anything else I should look into to ensure my security configuration works on iOS 9?

Thanks